# Event fired when browser comes out of "loading" state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Whenever we go to a website, the browser enters a "loading" state (spinner in place of favicon) till the site is loaded. 
Which jquery event is fired when browser comes out of the "loading state"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try anyone of :

`window.onload` or `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely help if you explained what you were trying to do. But since you asked for an jQuery event that fires when the browser has loaded the page, I would suggest you use the jQuery *ready* handler.

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

1. `$(document).ready(handler)`
2. `$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)`
3. `$(handler)`

The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

**EDIT:** Since we need an event when the browser has completed loading the page and all its resources, the jQuery `.load()` method would be more suitable.

The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. It is a shortcut for `.bind('load', handler)`.

Comment: I need to make some ajax requests after the browser has finished loading all page load network requests. I looked at dev toolkit and noticed that the browser comes out of the loading state only when all page load network requests are complete. That is why I asked for the event fired when browser comes out of loading state. And it seems jQuery ready handler is not correct answer as there are still network requests yet to return ad browser is still in loading state even after the $(document).ready event is fired. I need the event when browser finishes loading site.(stops spinning)